# Why there is no std::uses_allocator<std::optional>?

Tags: c++, allocator

There is an specialization of uses_allocator for std::variant, but not for std::optional. Why?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Standard 23.6.3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.optional#1):

> *Implementations are not permitted to use additional storage, such as dynamic memory, to allocate its contained value.*

So there is no need for an allocator.

Though the same is true for variant [23.7.3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/variant#variant-1):

> *Implementations are not permitted to use additional storage, such as dynamic memory, to allocate the contained value.*

Apparently, the `uses_allocator` specialization for `std::variant` [was removed for C++17](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2901) (HT: @K-ballo!).

Answer (score 0):

Because

> If an optional contains a value, the value is guaranteed to be
>   allocated as part of the optional object footprint, i.e. no dynamic
>   memory allocation ever takes place. Thus, an optional object models an
>   object, not a pointer, even though the operator*() and operator->()
>   are defined.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

On the other hand, `std::variant` used to support allocators in earlier edition of the Standard, so I have the feeling this specialization is a remnant of those days.

Comment: a variant does not allocate memory as well.

Comment: @draganm17 I have an unsupported feeling that this is due to the original implementation of variants, which did.